# How to count the length of the content of a list in erlang?

Tags: erlang

For example: `["hello","world wide","1","2","3"]` the length would be 18 including the space between world and wide.

I have tried:
`string:len(lists:flatten([X|Y]))` 
but it removes spaces.

What I'm thinking of using this for:
I am creating a function that will return a list of as many words as possible but keeping it below the specified length.

Example:

```
-spec hello(list(string()), integer()) -> list(string()).

1> hello:limit_word(["Hello", "there my friend", "wassup!"],10).                                      
["Hello"]
2> hello:limit_word(["Hello", "there my friend", "wassup!"],22). 
["Hello", "there my friend"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flattening and taking the length of the total works fine:

```
1> L = ["hello","world wide","1","2","3"].
["hello","world wide","1","2","3"]
2> string:length(lists:flatten(L)).
18
```

You could alternatively sum the length of each part:

```
3> lists:sum([length(S) || S <- L ]).
18
```

Or you could implement your `limit_word` function like this:

```
-module(hello).
-export([limit_word/2]).

limit_word(L, Max) ->
    limit_word(L, Max, {0, []}).
limit_word([H|T], Max, {Size, Acc}) ->
    NewSize = Size + length(H),
    case NewSize > Max of
        false ->
            limit_word(T, Max, {NewSize, [H|Acc]});
        true->
            lists:reverse(Acc)
    end;
limit_word([], _, {_, Acc}) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

The `limit_word/2` is what's exported to the caller (same as in your original example). It just calls the `limit_word/3` function, which takes an extra argument: a tuple of current total length, `Size`, and accumulated words, `Acc`. We take the head of the list, add its length to `Size`, and if the total is less than `Max`, we call `limit_word/3` recursively, passing `NewSize` and a new list of words with the new word as its head and the existing list of words as its tail. But if `NewSize` exceeds `Max`, we return the reversed `Acc` list — reversed because we formed the list by adding new words to the head. It works just as you'd expect:

```
4> hello:limit_word(["Hello", "there my friend", "wassup!"],10).
["Hello"]
5> hello:limit_word(["Hello", "there my friend", "wassup!"],22).
["Hello","there my friend"]
```

Update: If the total length of all list elements is less than `Max`, we never hit the `true` case, so the final `limit_word/3` clause handles the empty input list by returning the reversed accumulator.

Comment: If the limit is >= than the word length, you get an error.

Comment: which bits in the function can I modify to get the word that has been taken off from the list?thanks.

Comment: Processing a word relies on the list `[H|T]`, where `H` is the word at the head of the list, and `T` is the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iolist_size/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#iolist_size-1):

```
> iolist_size(["hello","world wide","1","2","3"]).
18
```